# I need some clarity on Navigation Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a total of 3 views. A menu, the main view where the action happens, and a settings menu.

You can access the settings from both the menu and the main view and go back using the back button provided by the `Navigation Controller`.

In the main view I have hidden the `NavigationBar` to free some space, and there's a specific button to go back to the menu. From what I know and have read, I assume this just adds more and more views to the Navigation Stack if I keep going from the main view to the menu again and again, creating a lot of views in the stack.

I'd like someone to tell me whether my assumption is true or not, and evt. explain me the whole process behind navigating and views.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your specific button action?

Comment: @AlexeySobolevsky I just linked them directly to the other views.

Comment: Do it programmatically with `dismissViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController` has a property `viewControllers` which is the stack of view controllers that have been pushed there.

If you use push segues in your storyboard each time you trigger this segues you push the current controller to the stack.

If you have a special logic I suggest you manage controllers programmatically.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) might clear it all.

Comment: Do I even have to embed my view controllers in navigation controllers then?

Comment: I just don't understand the need for them. What are the benefits of embedding my views in the controllers?

Comment: One of the benefits is that you don't need to bother about navigation when you need to create an app with a simple and straight forward logic like Settings in iPhone where you have hierarchical view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically following types of `Segues` to navigate to any `viewController`

- Show (Push)
- Show Detail (Replace)
- Present Modally
- Present as Popover

And to move back use `Unwind Segue`

You can read more regarding this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html)